# disable elements in a form excluding one element

Tags: jquery, html

i have this code that disables elements in a html form:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var form = document.getElementById("form1");
        var elements = form.elements;
        for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; ++i) {
            elements[i].readOnly = true;
        }
    });
```

The code is working fine, but i want to be able to leave one element so its not read only.

i was thinking maybe putting an if statement within the for loop to say

```
if(id == element_id) {
    ...do not disable / make read only
}
```

Comment: just set the readOnly property after the for loop to false.

Comment: I'm confused on what the problem is -- as what you offered a possible solution should work fine. Have you tried a version of that pseudo code?

Comment: so basically, this code will disable all elements in a form. i want a way to disable all elements (as the code currently does) but be able to exclude certain elements to NOT disable

Comment: Add the if statement in the for loop `if(elements[i] === 'element_id'){return element[i].readOnly = false;}`

Comment: if i do an `alert(elements[i]);` i just see [object HTMLInputElement]

Comment: @charlie what you wanna do exactly ? If u only want to disable all elm except of one, why u dont set the html inline disable property ?

Comment: i have said what i want to do. basically disable the whole form except one element inside the form

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var form = document.getElementById("form1");
        var elements = form.elements;
        for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; ++i) {
        }
            elements[i].readOnly = true;
    });
```

Try changing to this.

Comment: how will this let me choose what element i still want active?